# How to somehow instantiate a class which partially implements an interface

Tags: java, oop

Suppose I have an interface `IBird`. It has many methods such as `eat()`, `walk()`, `run()` and `fly()`.

If a base class `Ostrich` wants to implement `IBird`, how should that go about it? Because `Ostrich` can't fly but can do all other stuff in `IBird`.

Comment: Your class must implement the whole interface. No choice. The closest you could do is throw an exception if somebody is trying to make an `Ostrich` fly. But that would be considered bad practice. and might lead to unsuspected crash.

Comment: main communication for programmers is CODE, not story

Comment: Did you take it from a c# book/blog? Starting an interface with `I` is unusual for java.

Comment: @JacekCz. Thx! That helped a lot, Zuckerberg!

Comment: @Oleg, just followed C# conventions. I'm getting started with Java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make `Ostrich` `abstract`. That might work in some situations, but not here since every instance of `Ostrich` would have to implement the missing functionality.

Another choice would be, as `Johny` pointed out, to throw a `UnsupportedOperationException`. But that might result in unexpected crashes which aren't good for the user.

A third way is to remove the method `fly()` from the interface `IBird` and only leave the stuff that **all** birds share. Then you make another interface `IBirdThatCanFly` which extends `IBird`. Then you can add the missing `fly()` method.

```
public interface IBird { //all birds
    public void eat();
    public void walk();
    public void run();
}

public interface IBirdThatCanFly extends IBird { //birds that can fly
    public void fly();
}

public class Ostrich implements IBird { //Ostrich can't fly
    public void eat() { ... }
    public void walk() { ... }
    public void run() { ... }
}
```

Comment: great! just one edit-Shouldn't Ostrich be implementing IBird?

Comment: Yes, of course :)

Answer (score 1):

You can throw the `UnsupportedOperationException` in the implementation of 
fly method in Ostrich class.

```
class Ostrich {

    void fly() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); // throws the UnsupportedOperationException if someone tries to call this method
    }

    // implementation of eat(), walk() and run() 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all birds cannot fly, `fly()` should probably not be declared in `Bird`.
You could introduce two interfaces to distinguish birds and flying birds.

A `Bird` interface that declares `eat()`, `walk()`, `run()` methods.
A `FlyingBird` interface that extends `Bird` and that declares a `fly()` method.

```
public interface Bird { 
    void eat();
    void walk();
    void run();
}

public interface FlyingBird extends Bird { 
   void fly();
}

public class Ostrich implements Bird {
    public void eat(){
      ...
    }
    public void walk(){
      ...
    }
    public void run(){
      ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Java 8 you can also use the default keyword in an interface.  This will allow you to write out a method to be used in the event that a class does not implement a method.

Comment: You can end with flying Ostriches if you do that.

Comment: This is just a workaround so the OP doesn't have to put the method in the class.  I never said it was a good workaround just an option.